# Compare a Collection#unmodifiableCollection to the Collection#singletonList in Java with JUnit

Tags: java, collections, junit, compare

Given collections:

```
Collection<MyObject> expected = Collections.singletonList(new MyObject);
Collection<MyObject> actual = Collections.unmodifiableCollection(new ArrayList<>(expected));
```

But asserting both with

```
assertSame(expected, actual);
```

I see an assertion error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
expected same:<[com.flyeralarm.autopattern.algorithm.JobTransform@8807e25]>
was not: <[com.flyeralarm.autopattern.algorithm.JobTransform@8807e25]>

Expected :[com.flyeralarm.autopattern.algorithm.JobTransform@8807e25]
Actual   :[com.flyeralarm.autopattern.algorithm.JobTransform@8807e25]
```

But both expected and actual are showing me the same hashCode. Why is the test then failing?

**UPDATE**

After trying to run the test using Assert#asserEquals I saw that expected is a SingletonList which in no way can be equal to the actual UnmodifiableCollection. Therefore I have another question: What is the best way to compare these two types of collections.

Comment: Show us how you compare those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to compare lists is to convert them to arrays and compare those with [assertArrayEquals](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertArrayEquals(java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object[])):

```
assertArrayEquals(expected.toArray(), actual.toArray());
```

To make it work well, your items in your list must provide a correct `equals()` method.

Comment: I consider marking your answer as "the right one" but you say this is one way. I am just curious whether this approach is the one most devs use to compare collections or are there some other ones I should be aware of? Thank you anyways for providing at least one way:)

Comment: The core point is: you don't want to get into the business of comparing two objects that are of different collection type. So, the given solution circumvents that. I would only suggest to use **assertThat** and the hamcrest **is** matcher instead of those dumb assertXyzEquals calls.

Comment: @Jägermeister This is what I actually do: Atm it looks like `assertThat(expectedCollection.toArray(), is(actualCollection.toArray()))`.

Comment: I say 'One way ...' because I don't know all the alternatives. Probably `assertThat` and the `matchers` would work too. But I haven't worked with them. So they might work and might be nicer than my approach.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the contents of your collections, you could use either the `Arrays.equals(...)` or `Arrays.deepEquals(...);` methods.

That way in your unit test you can do one of the following to compare them:

- `assertThat("Custom message for failure.", Arrays.equals(expected.toArray(), actual.toArray()), is(true));`
- `assertThat("Custom message for failure.", Arrays.deepEquals(expected.toArray(), actual.toArray()), is(true));`

Alternatively you can use `assertTrue(...);`

[See full JavaDocs here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepEquals(java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object[]))

Comment: The idea of using **assertThat** would be that it gives you so much better error messages than other asserts. But the way you are using it, that benefit would be completely lost ... because: when the arrays are not equal, the only thing you get printed would be something like  "true != false". Not exactly helpful.

Comment: @Jägermeister I agree but I was only posting a quick answer. I will amend accordingly;)